# PlaySound in c++ program using a directory

Tags: c++

I have a problem when playing a sound using the function `PlaySound()`on my current directory. In the following cases i receive a system beep sound and not my original file sound, except the first one where i have the whole directory.

This one works perfectly:

```
PlaySound(TEXT("C:\\Users\\Living Room\\Desktop\\Project\\sound\\lost.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
```

But i'm going to deliver my project to my teacher he won't have the same directory like mine, that's why i want to change the directory to something like that:

```
PlaySound(TEXT("sound\\lost.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
```

Hence the folder sound contains the file **lost.wav** and the **.cpp** file is out from the sound folder.

This is what i do if i move the **.cpp** to the sound folder:

```
PlaySound(TEXT("lost.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
```

Please i really need your help on this, do i have to change the project properties?  I use visual studio 2013, and have included the libraries windows.h, mmsystem.h and the library winmm.lib.

Comment: It does not matter where your .cpp file is stored. The path you supply is relative to your *executable* file.

Comment: but i have seen many examples where people dont call the whole directory. and it works,https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Fqh-8XqK0M

Comment: Then the sound file is in the same folder as the executable (which is a special case of my general statement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of [PlaySound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> PlaySound searches the following directories for sound files: the
>   current directory; the Windows directory; the Windows system
>   directory; directories listed in the PATH environment variable; and
>   the list of directories mapped in a network.

The "current directory" in Windows is wherever the application is run from. However, running the project in Visual Studio will use a different directory. You can find out (and change) which directory that is by looking in your project properties under Debugging > Working Directory.

In the files you give to your teacher, the sound directory will need to be in the same place *relative to the EXE* as the sound directory on your computer is *relative to the Working Directory* in Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks it's working now, i moved the sound folder where i have the .exe file.

Comment: @RichardRoberts Note that the current working directory of your program may be different from the location, where your `.exe` is placed. In fact this would be rarely the case.

Comment: @vrostu: "*The "current directory" in Windows is wherever the application is run from*" - that is not always true. The "current directory" is referring to the **Current Working Directory**, which can (and usually does) change during the process's lifetime, and is not even the executable's folder at process startup if the executable is launched from a Shortcut that specifies a different folder in its "Start in" field.

Comment: If you want to load a file using a *relative path* that is based on the executable's actual location, use `GetProcessFileName()` with a `NULL` module handle to get the calling process's actual path, strip off the filename from it (everything after the last `\\` character), append the relative path to the end of it, and then pass the whole thing to the API as the filename to load.